# Pandas filtering (~isin) is not working

Tags: python, pandas, filter

This is my data

```
 omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices

No    Text    
1     dcbjkd
2     hdgfhds
3     dsdfs
33    jhsda
40    ydgyua
```

I am expecting to filter data like this

```
omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices

No    Text    
3     dsdfs
40    ydgyua
```

This is what I did

```
user_internal = ['1','2','33']
omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices = omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices[~omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.isin(user_internal)]
```

The code above is not working, the output still like my original dataframe, what did I miss?

Comment: What is `omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.dtype` ? because it seems it is int, then need `user_internal = [1,2,33]`

Comment: This is maybe a clue
`omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices[omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.isin(user_internal)]` dataframe without entry

Comment: @jezrael : dtype('O')

Comment: Maybe some whitespaces, what is `omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.head().tolist()` ?

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 33, 40]

Comment: So it's integers then. But you're using strings to filter. Is the error making sense now?

Comment: Try `user_internal = [1,2,33]` and repeat the process.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I got the aswer

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thats working

Comment: You're welcome. I think you can delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem you have mixed types - numeric with strings.

```
omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.dtype
dtype('O')

omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.head().tolist()
[1, 2, 3, 33, 40]
```

So convert column `No` to strings:

```
user_internal = ['1','2','33']
mask = ~omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.astype(str).isin(user_internal)
omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices =  omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices[mask]
```

Or change `string`s from list to `int`s:

```
user_internal = [1,2,33]
mask = ~omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices.No.isin(user_internal)
omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices =  omzet_activity_paid_count_january_devices[mask]
```